# Stretched UV problem

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have an issue with the UV editor.
When i unwrap my shape the UV's are all stretched and consequently also the textures are stretched:

[image]
[image]

I applied all transforms to the object and i set the origin point to the center of mass.
Someone know why this happen?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you share your file via this link? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/    That way I can take a closer look.

Comment: Did you scale the object in object mode? Then apply the scale (Ctrl+A and choose scale)

Comment: Yes @susu , as i wrote in the post i applied all the transformation tu the object.